# Split Table Into 2 Tables With Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql

I have a table which I need to split into 2 tables. One table would be general information and the other would be more specific information. Lets call them `general_table` and `farming_table`.

`farming_table` needs to have a foreign key allowing me to link it to the `general_table`. I am unsure how to insert data into the `general_table` then get the id of the newly created row and use that when I create a row for the `farming_table`.

I have tried using this code:

```
INSERT INTO `general_table` (name, year)
SELECT name, year
FROM `original_table`;

INSERT INTO `farming_table` (general_table_id, seeds, vehicles)
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1, seeds, vehicles
FROM `original_table`
CROSS JOIN (select @rownum := 0) r;
```

The above code is perfect if you are only going to run it once. If I then had to run it again later when the `general_table` already had data lets say it has 10 rows of data so the next ID would be 11, when I run the above code the foreign keys wouldn't match up. The `general_table_id` would start at 1 but it should start at 11.

I know I can change this manually by changing the `CROSS JOIN` to this `CROSS JOIN (select @rownum := 10) r;` but lets presume I dont know what the last ID in the `general_table` is.

If anyone can think of a more robust way of achieving my goal I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Im confused by your question. Are you trying to split 1 table into 2? That code should work for what you have

Comment: @RyanGadsdon Hi I have just changed my example to explain it better.

Comment: I can achieve my goal using PHP Laravel Eloquent but I was just wondering if there was an easy way to do it in MySQL